# Batch Delete Videos From YouTube Favorites Playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to batch delete videos from the user his YouTube favorites using the YouTube v2 API. (See also https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_batch_processing)

Posting videos to the favorites in batch works nicely; and I can also remove single videos from the favorites without problem (This rules out a problem with authentication).

My request body is as follows, where `VIDEOID1` and `VIDEOID2` are the `<yt:favoriteId>`Ids found in their corresponding video xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
    <batch:operation type="delete"/>
    <entry><id>VIDEOID1</id></entry>
    <entry><id>VIDEOID2</id></entry>
</feed>
```

This is the response I get back however, where `UserID` ofcourse is the userID of the user and `BatchID` is the BatchID given by the service:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
   <id>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERID/favorites/batch/BATCHID</id>
   <updated>2014-01-31T14:50:54.948Z</updated>
   <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#favorite'/>
   <title>Batch Feed</title>
   <entry xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'>      
       <id>VIDEOID1</id>
       <updated>2014-01-31T14:50:54.948Z</updated>
       <title>Error</title>
       <content>Invalid entry Id/Uri</content>
       <batch:status code='400' reason='Invalid entry Id/Uri'/>
   </entry>
   <entry xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch'>
       <id>VIDEOID2</id>
       <updated>2014-01-31T14:50:54.949Z</updated>
       <title>Error</title>
       <content>Invalid entry Id/Uri</content>
       <batch:status code='400' reason='Invalid entry Id/Uri'/>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

It states `Invalid entry Id/Uri` for the videos I try to remove, while when I remove them by singular delete request with the same ID, it works.

Is batch deleting videos from favorites not supported, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to work, thanks to this question and answer: [Batch deleting videos using YouTube API and HTTpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259704/batch-deleting-videos-using-youtube-api-and-httpwebrequest)

The trick was using the user its `userId` instead of `default`, and to use to complete video URL as `id`.

The batch URL looks like this:

```xml
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERID/favorites/batch?v=2&alt=json
```

The request looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
    <batch:operation type="delete"/>
    <entry>
        <id>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERID/favorites/VIDEOID1?v=2</id>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERID/favorites/VIDEOID2?v=2</id>
    </entry>
</feed>
```